# ElasticSearch: Best practice for working with frequently changing fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some fields in my document that have hundreds of updates per minute, such as download counter, likes.

Knowing that it is costly to change these fields and reindex, what is the best way to update these fields?

There is still one however, these fields are used for sorting, so separating these fields in another index does not seem like a good way to perform the sorting, as my index already has more than 40k documents. I don't see an efficient way to do this.

One approach we use is an index for this is to separate likes and downloads in other indexes, and during the search, we do a count with aggregation, it works well, but we cannot order by likes or downloads, as they are in separate indices.

How can we deal with this?

Comment: can you describe the performance issues that you are encountering with these updates? 40k docs is a really small number of documents.

Comment: 40 thousand in a few weeks, it will increase drastically, each document can have thousands of downloads per day, this would imply thousands of updates to that document, to increase the download counter for example

Comment: I tend to think that it is a bit [premature](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) to try to optimize a problem that hasn't been witnessed yet :-) Have you tested your logic on a much bigger amount of documents and actually seen it break?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, an `update` is costly in Elasticsearch (append new doc, mark deleted on old).

I think you can try `append` (just like insert, not `update`) new status of your counters like `likes` and `downloads` with timestamp.

Not sure exactly about your data.

It can be accumulative status, or separated event for each field.

For example, accumulative status (quotes are removed just for demo):

```
# document 1
{
  @timestamp: T1,
  likes: 180,
  downloads: 10000 
}

# document 2
{
  @timestamp: T2,
  likes: 181,
  downloads: 10100 
}

# then do subtracts with painless or your backend program to get diff in a given time range.

# consider delete old data by _delete_by_query depends on your need; since old accumulated status maybe useless.
```

or separated event

```
# document 1
{
  @timestamp: T1,
  likes: 0,
  downloads: 4 
}

# document 2
{
  @timestamp: T2,
  likes: 1,
  downloads: 10
}

# do some agg (aggregation) later.
```

In this way, the `append` should be fine if the data is only few hundreds per minute.

I prefer separated one, since it's easier to do `agg` later to display what I want.

Comment: I already do something similar to this, I have an index for downloads and likes, where each document records a download, for example, with some data, such as date, `user_id,` `product_id`, and to count the likes and downloads I use aggregation with search, counting the total , however, this approach cannot order products by likes/downloads, as the counting is in other indexes, it would be expensive for each product to access the index and count.

Comment: I am not sure why you don't put product and like/download event into single index? For example: `{@timestamp: T1, product_id: 1, likes: 2, downloads: 5}` , `{@timestamp: T2, product_id: 1, likes: 1, downloads: 3}`. Or you may need to provide more specific example about your data structure

Answer (score 0):

Changing a field value is expensive in elasticsearch because internally it doesn't actually support it. Every single change results in an old record being deleted and a new record with all updated and non-updated fields indexed. In turn, these added and deleted records lead to constant merge churn.

One possible solution to reduce this indexing load is to split records in two parts - one large part will contain rarely (or preferably never) changing fields, and another smaller part will contain the frequently updated fields. Both parts will be indexed in the same index but in order to preserve the relationship between the large part and corresponding small part you will need to establish it using the [join field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html). In order to be able to sort using the child record you will need to be able to express the sort key as a single floating point number and use it as a score the way it is explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.10/parent-join.html).

There is now free lunch though, and this setup will be slower then just plain search, so you are somewhat trading you search performance for reduced indexing load. Saying this, 40k documents is not such a big index, so I would expect it to handle growth without much sweat.